# opencv knn TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, opencv3.0, knn

I am trying to follow the tutorial http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_knn/py_knn_opencv/py_knn_opencv.html and replaced `KNearest` with `cv2.m1.KNearest_create()` but  i am getting `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('digits.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Now we split the image to 5000 cells, each 20x20 size
cells = [np.hsplit(row,100) for row in np.vsplit(gray,50)]

# Make it into a Numpy array. It size will be (50,100,20,20)
x = np.array(cells)

# Now we prepare train_data and test_data.
train = x[:,:50].reshape(-1,400).astype(np.float32) # Size = (2500,400)
test = x[:,50:100].reshape(-1,400).astype(np.float32) # Size = (2500,400)

# Create labels for train and test data
k = np.arange(10)
train_labels = np.repeat(k,250)[:,np.newaxis]
test_labels = train_labels.copy()

# Initiate kNN, train the data, then test it with test data for k=1
cv2.m1.KNearest_create()
knn.train(train,train_labels)
ret,result,neighbours,dist = knn.find_nearest(test,k=5)

# Now we check the accuracy of classification
# For that, compare the result with test_labels and check which are wrong
matches = result==test_labels
correct = np.count_nonzero(matches)
accuracy = correct*100.0/result.size
print accuracy
```

(i am using a raspberry pi and followed this tutorial to install open cv http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/ subsequently i pip installed matplotlib)

Answer (score 3):

parameter cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE is missing and change knn.find_nearest(test,k=5) to below code.This is new in openCv3, please refer to openCv official site [http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/dd/de1/classcv_1_1ml_1_1KNearest.html](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/dd/de1/classcv_1_1ml_1_1KNearest.html#ab0ce3fa7a242f3418938592f4d935b81)

```
    ` knn.train(train, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, train_labels)
      ret, result, neighbours, dist = knn.findNearest(test, k=5)`
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing one parameter, but I notice that a lot of people have questions about this section of the tutorial, so here's the whole final section adjusted to work with python3 and the modern openCV library.

```
knn = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()
knn.train(trainData, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, responses)
ret, results, neighbours, dist = knn.findNearest(newcomer, k=5)

print("result: ", results,"\n")
print("neighbours: ", neighbours,"\n")
print("distance: ", dist)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('digits.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Now we split the image to 5000 cells, each 20x20 size
cells = [np.hsplit(row,100) for row in np.vsplit(gray,50)]

# Make it into a Numpy array. It size will be (50,100,20,20)
x = np.array(cells)

# Now we prepare train_data and test_data.
train = x[:,:50].reshape(-1,400).astype(np.float32) # Size = (2500,400)
test = x[:,50:100].reshape(-1,400).astype(np.float32) # Size = (2500,400)

# Create labels for train and test data
k = np.arange(10)
train_labels = np.repeat(k,250)[:,np.newaxis]
test_labels = train_labels.copy()

# Initiate kNN, train the data, then test it with test data for k=1
knn = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()
knn.train(train, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, train_labels)
ret, results, neighbours, dist = knn.findNearest(test, k=5)

#print("result: ", results,"\n")
#print("neighbours: ", neighbours,"\n")
#print("distance: ", dist)
matches = result=test_labels
correct = np.count_nonzero(matches)
accuracy = correct*100.0/result.size
print(accuracy)
```

Comment: Hi! What is the problem you are having? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) some guidance on asking a good question. So that people can run your code, you need to provide a copy of `digits.png`

Answer (score -1):

doc of opencv said that:

> findNearest(...)  |      findNearest(samples, k[, results[,
>   neighborResponses[, dist]]]) -> retval, results, neighborResponses,
>   ...

---

not `knn.find_nearest(test,k=5)`

you can run

`help(cv2.ml.KNearest_create())`

then you will see.
by the way ,there are losts erros on opencv website

Comment: Please format your code and clarify your answer.  This answer is very difficult to read.